# "program blocker" which blocks programs for a specified amount of time

Tags: windows, time-management, parental-control, process-control

I am looking for a free "program blocker" which blocks programs for a specified amount of time (e.g. 1 hour). The program must (at least) be able to anticipate the following "tricks"

- go to task manager and kill the monitoring program
- still block the specified program after reboot
- when a file is renamed (e.g. firefox.exe) the renamed file can still not be executed
- changing the time on your computer does not tamper the schedule
- when the monitoring program is initiated even the administrator account cannot reverse the schedule

Thanks in advance

Comment: Shouldn't the administrator be able to do anything by definition?

Comment: Exactly. Otherwise, entering a wrong schedule (worst case: "Now and forever") would mean buying a new computer (well, at least re-installing Windows).