# Software that locks out other software for a certain period of time

Tags: windows, gratis, productivity, health

So long story short, I have ADD. Unsurprisingly, even with techniques and stuff that learned over years I get distracted very easily, very much so when I am using a computer (yay for being a comp sci student). Accordingly, I am looking for software I can use that block access to programs that can and usually do distract me.

Take note that I am aware of the question found [here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/11352/program-blocker-which-blocks-programs-for-a-specified-amount-of-time) which is similar, but, I am little less strict in the sense that it does not have to anticipate any tricks indicated in the other question. It is more for the case of denying me the initial impulsion.

The only requirement I have is it works with Windows and is free. The program can even be something built into Windows already, but I am just unaware of it.